# invalid identifier in sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I wrote the query like that using self join because the `EmployeeID` should be a `primary key` and a `foreign key` at the same time - is that way true? and the sql developer show this to me what does it mean?

> SQL Error: ORA-00904: "E"."EMPLOYEESUPERVISOR": invalid identifier
>   00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"

```
create table Employees
(
    EmployeeID varchar2(50) not null primary key,
    EmployeeName varchar2(50) unique,
    EmployeeSupervisor varchar2(50),
    constraint fk_EmployeeID foreign key (EmployeeID) references 
    Employees(EmployeeID)
);

insert into Employees values (098-23-456,'Sue Miller');
insert into Employees values (107-55-789,'Stan Getz');
insert into Employees values (123-44-347,'Jim Jason');
insert into Employees values (547-33-243,'Bill Blass');
insert into Employees values (678-44-546,'Robert Lewis');

select E.EmployeeID,
      E.EmployeeName,
      M.EmployeeSupervisor AS Manager 
from Employees E, 
      Employees M 
where E.EmployeeSupervisor = M.EmployeeID;
```

Comment: Your code makes no sense and won't come close to running as written.

Comment: It says employeesupversior is unknown column. Are you trying to create a foriegn key on employeesupversior that refers to employee id?

Comment: If EmployeeSupervisor is the ID of an employee then the foreign key should be `(EmployeeSupervisor) references Employees (EmployeeID)`. Anyway the error doesn't seem to be related to this, check that the table has indeed a `EmployeeSupervisor` field, maybe is missing or bad written. Finally, don't use `WHERE` to join tables, use `JOIN`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there are some minor problems in your insert queries.

1. you declared EmployeeID as varchar2 but you haven't enclosed ID values with ' so you are basically trying to insert the result of the mathematical operation 107-55-789 which means -737.
2. you are not specifying fields names in your insert statements, so you have to give the values of every fields. You have 3 fields but you are providing 2 values in each statement.

so you may test with these insert statements:

```
insert into Employees values ('107-55-789','Stan Getz', null);
insert into Employees values ('123-44-347','Jim Jason', '123-44-347');
insert into Employees values ('547-33-243','Bill Blass', null);
insert into Employees values ('678-44-546','Robert Lewis', '123-44-347');
```

take a look at this oracle fiddle to see the result:

[Oracle Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/80220/10)